# Hive 0.12.0 and Cassandra 2.1.4 Integration

Tags: cassandra, hive, integration

For past two days i am try for hive Cassandra integration.but in online i am getting examples for hive-0.9.0 and Cassandra 1.2 but i want to integrate hive-0.12.0 with Cassandra-2.1.4. please help me to solve out this because integrating two old version is not useful for me.So i am using **Hadoop-1.2.1 , hive-0.12.0 and Cassandra-2.1.4** Help needed

Answer (score 2):

The Hive driver that supports modern Cassandra versions is not open source. It is included in the DataStax Enterprise release. It is possible to connect to current versions using the old [cash](https://github.com/tuplejump/cash) driver, but it's no longer being actively worked on, and it may require some tinkering.